# Initializing multiple connections to firebase are failing in Nodejs for firebase-admin NPM

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I have the following code trying to connect to Firebase Realtime Database in NodeJS using the latest `firebase-admin` package (10.x):

```js
import { database } from 'firebase-admin';
import { applicationDefault, initializeApp } from 'firebase-admin/app';

const app = initializeApp({
    credential: applicationDefault(),
    databaseURL: 'https://DATABASE_NAME.firebaseio.com'
}, 'xx');

const db = database(app);
```

The issue is that the `database(app)` call fails with following error:

```
TypeError: _this.ensureApp(...).database is not a function
```

I believe that my code is correct since I need the ability to connect to multiple databases...

Anybody knows what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error say database is not a function. Could you check the type of "database"?

Answer (score 0):

The following import is incorrect:

```js
import { database } from 'firebase-admin';
```

The correct modular import is:

```js
import { getDatabase } from 'firebase-admin/database';

getDatabase()
```

Or, if using the old namespaced API:

```js
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'

admin.database()
```